# Как спарсить сайт с неизменным url?

Tags: python, парсер, web-scraping, веб-скрейпинг

Стоит такая задача: спарсить всех перевозчиков и экспедиторов-перевозчиков из определенных городов с сайта [ati.su](http://ati.su). Пытаюсь сделать это со [страницы рейтинга всех фирм](https://ati.su/rating), но при вводе определенного города(например, Москва) и смене страницы url не меняется.

Отловил get-запрос при смене города: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Видим, что сайт похоже получает список фирм с помощью метода `getFirmsRating`, но в официальном API я такой функции не нашел

Comment: Если вы раскодируете GET-запрос из URL кодировки в обычный текст, увидите, что там есть JSON-обьект "Geo" со значением, вроде {"value":"2_3611","text":"Москва,+Москва+(регион),+Россия"....}
И, насколько я могу судить, за отбор по городу отвечает параметр "value". Поиграйтесь с его значением. У меня ответы 200 приходили на значения с паттерном 2_*. То есть от 2_1, 2_2 ... 2_2115 и т.д. Перебирайте все эти варианты, и будет вам счастье))

Comment: Спасибо большое, в общих чертах понял, как все реализовать